# Using mozImageSmoothingEnabled by the help of JSNI in GWT

Tags: gwt, html5-canvas, jsni

Gecko 1.9.2 introduced the mozImageSmoothingEnabled property to the canvas element; if this Boolean value is false, images won't be smoothed when scaled. This property is true by default.

```
 ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false
```

I want to use this property in GWT.
How can I implement

```
 public static void setMozImageSmooting(Canvas canvas, boolean value)
 {
    ...
 }
```

by using JSNI?

Answer (score 2):

Well I haven't tried it, but I assume, you should first get the Context in Java:

```
Context ctx = canvas.getContext2d();
setMozImageSmooting(ctx, false);
```

Then implement

```
 public static native void setMozImageSmooting(Context ctx, boolean value) /*-{
    ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = value;
 }-*/;
```

(Feel free to correct this answer, if it contains errors, because I can't test it right now.)